# NSURLSessionUploadTask request pause and resume causes 400

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

While app goes to background, I pause the the upload task for Amazon S3 and then resuming the same task on foreground. This causes sometimes `NSURLSession`'s delegate method `didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error` to throw 400 and error as `nil` and fails to upload.

How could I solve this problem?